Why does this series representation for $\frac{x}{e^x-1}$ diverge for $|x| \gt 2\pi$?
I have found the following formula for $\frac{x}{e^x-1}$:
$$1+x\zeta(0)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\zeta(1-2n)x^{2n}}{(2n-1)!}$$
However, plugging this into the Wolfram Cloud plot I find that the series shoots up to positive or negative infinity - depending on the number of terms to which it is computed - at $x=2\pi$ and $x=-2\pi$. Why does this happen? And can someone tell me where I can find more information on this particular series? Because I did not learn about it from an external source, but from my own derivations.

That function has a pole at 2πi. 2π and -2π are the same distance from the center.

the "why" is pretty much that $e^{2 \pi i} = 1$, there is then a theorem that if a power series converges for some $x$ it needs to also converge for all $t$ with $|t| < |x|$
